# How far back is normal to backtest an ATS ?

Tags: algorithmic-trading, backtesting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How much data is needed to validate a short-horizon trading strategy?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/1891/how-much-data-is-needed-to-validate-a-short-horizon-trading-strategy)

How far back do people usually backtest trading systems? months? years?

Comment: ATS usually stands for "alternative trading system" (like the ECNs), not "automated trading system". I was really confused by your question title.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question has been asked before, but it's not about time-frames per se, but about having enough results to satisfy whatever statistical criteria you have decided to adopt.